# VBA .Find and .Union Method

Tags: vba

I'm new to VBA. I want to find the headers of six columns and join them using the union method. Once they are joined as BigColumns, I want to change the font size to 14.

I've already tried looping, but given that I am new to this I wanted to try a simpler way. I can successfully run this code on one range, such as TC1, and change the font to 14. But as soon as I try combining ranges, it fails.

```
Sub ASOLDPrintFormatTesting2()   
Dim Table As Range
Dim BigColumns As Range
Dim TC1, TC2, TC3, TC4, TC5, TC6 As Range
'TC stands for Table Columns These individual ranges are joined through 
Union Method

Set ReferenceCell = ActiveCell
Set WS = Sheets(2)

With WS
    Set ReferenceCell = Cells.Find(What:="Source #", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    'Make Source # the Reference Cell, or the equivalent of A1
If Not ReferenceCell Is Nothing Then
    Set ReferenceCell = Cells.Find(What:="Sample #", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
End If
    'Make Sample # the Reference Cell

Set Table = ReferenceCell.CurrentRegion

With Table
    Set TC1 = .Find(What:="Source Well", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Set TC2 = .Find(What:="Sample ID", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Set TC3 = .Find(What:="VerboseConc_uM", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Set TC4 = .Find(What:="VerboseConc_ug/ml", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Set TC5 = .Find(What:="Mol Wt.", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Set TC6 = .Find(What:="N/Mole", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    'Find all headers of BigColumns

    Set BigColumns = Application.Union(Range("TC1"), Range("TC2"), _
    Range("TC3"), Range("TC4"), Range("TC5"), Range("TC6"))
    'Union of all headerrs as BigColumns

    If Not BigColumns Is Nothing Then
    Else
        MsgBox "'BigColumns' not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

With BigColumns
    .Cells.Font.Size = 14
End With
'Test to see if BigColumns works

End With

End Sub
```

No error messages are produced when the code runs.

Comment: For the sake of asking, why do you want to do it this way?  Between looping through an array of `What:=` terms and individually changing, etc., there're many other ways.

Comment: Additional... `With WS //   Set ReferenceCell = Cells.Find()`; what's the point of the with-statement if you're not using it?  `.cells.find()` may help.

Comment: I'm not set on doing it this way, I just understood how to set this one up.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array (will give a snippit example), you should be able to loop and save some time and possible issues where things are not found:

```
dim arr as variant, i as long
arr = array("Source Well","Sample ID") 'can add more
with table
    for i = lbound(arr) to ubound(arr)
        set f = .find(what:=arr(i))
        if not f is nothing then f.font.size = 14
    next i
end with
```

-untested code-

You find your item, if it's not found it skips changing the font size.

Comment: postscript, threw this into my excel, swapped `Table` for `ActiveSheet.Cells` and it worked, so should be solid for the purposes.